# Link to Christianity.StackExchange quickly

Tags: discussion

I just found out that [Stack Exchange has their very own link shortener](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk) and I wanted to be sure that the community here was aware of it.

To link to Christianity.StackExchange.com quickly you can type:

http://s.tk/christianity

---

<sup>It might be too late, but I think it should be shorter than "christianity". Not sure what though. I might start a new meta post for that.</sup>

Comment: Their standard practice is to use the subdomain on the shortened link so i doubt it will get much shorter.

Comment: @waxeagle [The Biology Site has requested `bio`](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/268/s-tk-url-for-biology-se) I don't see why the SE staff will not do it for them.

Answer (score 1):

I would think s.tk/christ would be acceptable. I doubt there's going to be a Stack Exchange about Jesus himself.

Comment: Or `s.tk/jesus` which is even shorter!

Comment: +1. I didn't think of that. I do wonder if that might be getting too far away.

I'd suggest Xian, but I don't think people would know what it meant, and I don't want to upset the people who believe that Xmas is removing the Christ from Christmas.

Comment: @trlkly If you try to prevent upsetting people who are upset about something because of their own ignorance then you are going to be walking on eggshells the rest of your life. Not to sound snooty, but the people I have met who actually think that the `X` is meant to replace Christ and secularize christmas and other things are not the kind of people I want posting on an intellectual site. They seem to not care that they might be misinformed and will continually spout this even after you correct them.

Comment: So far I like `christ`, short for `christianity`. I don't like `jesus` because there are a lot of clashing opinions even within Christianity. I am partial to `xian` however. Sounds really techie, like a linux distro or something.

Comment: @fredsbend: But, as a Christian, I have a requirement not to unnecessarily stir up strife amongst my fellow Christians. And I just don't see reclaiming the X as being all that important. Plus I think it would have the recognizablility problem that s.tk/xp would also have. You even thought it looked like a Linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the Chi-Rho symbol, the symbol of Constantine and the first two letters of *Christos* in Greek? It's not likely to clash with any other Stack Exchange site.

http://s.tk/xp

Comment: a little weird though for the casual christian that is unaware of these things. I was tossing around `xian` or `chrstn` or maybe just `x` but I bet SE would not accept that one.

Comment: I wouldn't want to be confused for a site about Windows XP. +1 for being pretty darn short and making some sense.

Comment: Windows XP won't be a problem after April. (I think it's April it goes out of support)

Comment: I remember in 2009 reading that XP support officially ends in 2014, but for some reason it will still be illegal to use the software without a legitimate key.

Comment: Wouldn't it be awesome if MS released the source and gave it to the open source community? What they could do with it would be awesome.

Comment: The problem I have is that those letters aren't Chi Rho or how those letters are usually transliterated. "XP" would work, as those at least look the same, but "xp" are completely different letters. I think even Christians who are knowledgeable of Greek wouldn't recognize it.